# How do I solve `$(' is not allowed as a global variable name when invoking Ruby from Ant

Tags: ruby, ant, homebrew

I have a need to install Homebrew on a remote Mac box and due to some design decisions the only way I can run anything in that machine is by executing an Ant script.

I'm trying to adapt the [instructions from the Homebrew website](https://brew.sh/) and run the equivalent of this:

```sh
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

...from an Ant build file. Here it is:

```xml
<project name="default" default="homebrew">
    <target name="ruby" >
        <echo message="Checking Ruby..." />
        <exec executable="/usr/bin/ruby">
            <arg value="--version"/>
        </exec>
        <echo message="Checking Ruby done!" />
    </target>
    <target name="homebrew" depends="ruby">
        <echo message="Installing Homebrew..." />
        <exec executable="/usr/bin/ruby">
            <arg line=' -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"'/>
        </exec>
        <echo message="Homebrew installation done!" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Here's what I'm getting:

```sh
ruby:
     [echo] Checking Ruby...
     [exec] ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
     [echo] Checking Ruby done!

homebrew:
     [echo] Installing Homebrew...
     [exec] -e:1: `$(' is not allowed as a global variable name
     [exec] Result: 1
     [echo] Homebrew installation done!
```

How do I get around this `$(' is not allowed as a global variable name` problem? Is it possible to somehow escape the `$` sign?
In a nutshell, how can I adapt this Ant build file to install Homebrew? I could just place the Homebrew installation command in a bash script, but I'd rather just fix the syntax to do it directly from Ant.

Comment: It's highly unclear what you are asking. Are you asking how you can use POSIX shell command interpolation in Ant? Then, the answer is: you can't, you need to use either a POSIX shell or Ant command interpolation. Why are you using `curl` in the first place, doesn't Ant have its own way of downloading assets?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I've edited the question to attempt to clarify.

Comment: It's still not very clear what you are trying to do. The string you are passing to Ruby to evaluate is not valid Ruby code. Why are you trying to execute shell code using Ruby?

Comment: @JörgWMittag the `curl` command downloads a Ruby script. This is just the one-line installation that the Homebrew website recommends.

Comment: Yes, the curl downloads a Ruby script. But, the curl command itself is not Ruby code, so why are you executing it as Ruby? That's what confuses me.

Comment: I'm no Ruby expert but `man ruby` shows `-e command     Specifies script from command-line while telling Ruby not to search the rest of the arguments for a script file name.` So this is just telling Ruby to run the cript downloaded by `cUrl`. That's all.

Comment: Yes, but you are not telling Ruby to run the script downloaded by curl. You are telling Ruby to run curl. That doesn't work, because curl is not a Ruby method, it is a shell command. You need to run curl with the shell, not with Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant's `exec` task often chokes on complex command line operations. In general, it's better to stick with multiple `exec` steps, containing a series of separate `arg value`s rather than full `arg line`s.

Try this instead:

```
<target name="ruby">
    <echo message="Checking Ruby..." />

    <exec executable="/usr/bin/ruby">
        <arg value="--version"/>
    </exec>

    <echo message="Checking Ruby done!" />
</target>

<target name="homebrew" depends="ruby">
    <echo message="Installing Homebrew..." />

    <exec executable="curl" outputproperty="homebrew.install">
        <arg value="-fsSL" />
        <arg value="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install" />
    </exec>

    <exec executable="/usr/bin/ruby" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-e"/>
        <arg value="${homebrew.install}"/>
    </exec>

    <echo message="Homebrew installation done!" />
</target>
```

Here the remote install script is first curl'd and stored as an Ant property using `exec`'s `outputproperty` attribute, then passed as an argument to ruby.

(Note I also added `failonerror="true"` to the installation step but this was just a use case assumption on my part. It can be removed if you want.)

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.